# What kind of lightbulb do I need?

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I’m moving into a my new home and fixing things that I can. Does anyone know what kind of light bulb I need for this ceiling fan light ?  My best guess is a T4 based on googling but the slot has a meta connector in each side. It also reads 500w

[image][image]

Comment: FYI I believe there are now LED's to fit those old halogen  fixtures.

Comment: Yes they do make led's in the R7S style. I am not sure if they go up to 500w equivelent but I have purchased some 300 equivelent for work lights waiting to see how they hold up on portable lamps.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a 118mm j-type long / r7s base halogen lamp they do come in 500w , but also smaller 300,150,100 & 50w. When installing a halogen use the packing material or a clean tissue to hold the lamp. Finger oils cause the lamp to overheat and sometimes explode.

Comment: Thank you so much ed. I’ll give this a try and this gives me a great starting point.